# Return JSON object from a spring-boot rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, angular5

I'm trying to check if the username is unique in spring-boot.
I want to send the result as JSON object.
This is the REST controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/checkEmailUnique",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkEmailUnique(@RequestBody String username){

    AppUser app = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    if(app!=null){
        // I want to return somthing like emailNotTaken: true
    }
    else{
        // and here : emailNotTaken: false  
    }
}
```

I want to get the result in angular so I can show an error message in my component.
How can I do that?

**Angular side**

client.Service.Ts

```
checkEmailNotTaken(email:string){
    if(this.authService.getToken()==null) {
      this.authService.loadToken();
    }
    return this.http.post(this.host+
      "/checkEmailUnique/",{email},{headers:new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.authService.getToken()})});
  }
```

in client.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      prenom: ['', Validators.required],
      nom: ['', Validators.required],
      tel: ['', Validators.required],
      cin: ['', Validators.required],
      username: ['', Validators.required , Validators.email  , this.validateEmailNotTaken.bind(this)],
      passwordG: this.formBuilder.group({
        password: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(9)]],
        Confirmationpassword : ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(9)]]

      }, {validator: passwordMatch})

    });
  }

    validateEmailNotTaken(control: AbstractControl) {
        return this.clientService.checkEmailNotTaken(control.value).map(res => {
          return  // what to do here ?
        });

      }
```

**EDIT**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/checkEmailUnique",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public EmailStatusCheckJson checkEmailUnique(@RequestBody final String username){

        final EmailStatusCheckJson returnValue = new EmailStatusCheckJson();


         AppUser app = userRepo.findByUsername(username);


         if(app!=null){
             returnValue.setEmailIsAvailable(false);
         }
         else{
             returnValue.setEmailIsAvailable(true);

         }

         return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: just return "{emailNottaken:true}" and "{emailNottaken:false}"

Comment: I tried this , but i don't how to get it in angular5 side , i've added my coded if you can see it again :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the spring-boot-starter-web,
your project is already set to return JSON.
Instead of `String` as the return value from `checkEmailUnique`,
use an object type that you create.

Here is an example:

```
public class EmailStatusCheckJson
{
    private Boolean emailIsAvailable;

    public Boolean getEmailIsAvailable()
    {
        return emailIsAvailable;
    }

    public void setEmailIsAvailable(
        final Boolean newValue)
    {
        emailIsAvailable = newValue
    }
}


@RequestMapping(value="/checkEmailUnique",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public EmailStatusCheckJson checkEmailUnique(@RequestBody final String username)
{
    final EmailStatusCheckJson returnValue = new EmailStatusCheckJson();

    if (...) // email is available.
    {
        returnValue.setEmailIsAvailable(true);
    }
    else
    {
        returnValue.setEmailIsAvailable(false);
    }

    return returnValue;        
}
```

***Edited*** added more example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , i've did the same as in your answer , how can i get this value in angular5 by the end ?

Comment: There is no "get it in angular".  the front end (in your case an angular) app will send an HTTP request to the checkEmailUnique URL and the response will contain the JSON that is created by the checkEmailUnique method.

Answer (score 1):

Rest method have a return type as String .In place of any String you can use a user defined object where(inside there) put a boolean variable e.g. status there you can send whether the username is present or not. According to the response from the rest side you can forward towards angular.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this way using ResponseEntity as the return value to your RestController

```
public ResponseEntity<?> checkEmailUnique(@RequestBody String username){
    AppUser app = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    if(null != app) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build(); // Will return a 400 response
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build(); // Will return a 200 response
}
```

Base on the response type you could directly identify if the email exits or not instead of returning json in this case.